# Android - Is it possible for the RemoteMediaClient state to be updated from a custom receiver app?

Tags: android, google-cast

If we create a custom receiver app using HTML5/Javascript to play music, is it possible that the state of a `com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.media.RemoteMediaClient` will be updated ?
The purpose is to send custom message (as play/pause) with specific data to this receiver and is to have all related states always in the instance of RemoteMediaClient. 
If it is possible, how to attach the Media Player to the Receiver API ?
My sender app is an android application using the CAF SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load media from a custom receiver: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/advanced#tip-loading-media-using-contentid-contenturl-and-entity

This will ensure that both the receiver and the sender app will stay in sync with regards to the media state of the current track and any media in a queue.